# I want to convert date function into julian date

Tags: php

I want to convert 005 to 5 January in php. I tried `GregorianToJD(03, 02, 2017);` function but i cant get my desired output. For example if i convert todays date `03 feb` in julian this will be `feb 034`.

Comment: Look at [date](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with the `z` mask: `echo sprintf('%03d', date('z', mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2017)) + 1);`

Comment: Did you mean that the function is not working right? `echo jdtogregorian(gregoriantojd(03, 02, 2017));//Result: 3/2/2017 `

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks works like a charm you saved me

Comment: Please include your code so others with this issue understand. Thanks.

Comment: Cleanup up title by moving example to question body. Added code formatting.